# Laravel, How to separate the month and year from one input as in a credit card

Tags: php, laravel

How to separate the month and year from a single text that contains the year and month in the same sentence as in a credit card, I want to save it as month=12, year=2022 if the input was 12/22

the input as below

```
 <input placeholder="MM/YY" type="text" name="expiry">
```

in controller

```
 $request->input('expiry');
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$date = explode('/', $request->input('expiry')); // 12/22
$month = date[0];
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', $date[1]);
// get the full year
$year = $dates->format('Y'); // output : 2022
```

But be aware, if you use the format character 'y' in `createFromFormat()`...
PHP documentation says:

'y' > A two digit representation of a year (which is assumed to be in the range 1970-2069, inclusive)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP method `print_r(explode("/",$str));`
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkMe = "12/19";
echo date('m',strtotime($checkMe));
echo "<br>";
echo date('y',strtotime($checkMe));
```

Answer (score 0):

On the input you can use a javascript mask with the format MM/YYYY
and in the controller just `explode('/',$request->input('expiry'));` with `month = $exploded[0] and year = $exploded[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP explode(separator,string,limit) function to get month and year separated.

Note that here the parameter limit is optional.

According to your main question, it should be like the following.

```
$expiry = explode("/", $request->expiry);
$month = $expiry[0];
$year = $expiry[1];
```